# Can't install Xcode4 because the dmg is not recognized

Tags: xcode4

while trying to install xcode4 it is showing an error as not recognized. Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of error? Please give more details. Your download might be corrupted or there is a problem with you computer, how should we know?

Comment: may i know what are the details you required .? i am using mac OS x snow leopard 10.6.6 and some body downloaded the xcode_4.0.1_and_ios_sdk_4.3.dmg and while i am trying to install it showing not recognized. k if it is corrupted then if i want to download again am i need paid member ship (99 $) or with free member ship we can download.

Comment: I had several problems downloading xcode 3.2.x, many times my download was corrupted. You can get xcode 4 for about 5$ (not sure maybe 4$) from appstore.

Comment: are you able to open the package?

Comment: k no actually i have that .dmg file if i double click on that it showing not recognized .only

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

1. locate and select the **.dmg** file
2. **Get Info** 'Command I', or 'Finder' -> 'File, Get Info'
3. locate the **Open with: section**
4. open with: popup menu - select **DiskImageMounter**, then click **Change All**
5. if DiskImageMounter is **not listed** , select the
   **Other...** menu item. Go to
   `/System/Library/CoreServices/`.
   Here you should fine
   DiskImageMounter. Select it, then
   the 'Change All' button, and
   finally, the 'Continue' button.

If that does not help try another mounting software. If that does not help too you have to redownload xcode4.

Comment: thank you so much for your reply. it is not working may i know ur good name pls.

Comment: Have you selected DiskImageMounter and it still says not recognized? If so then you need to redownload it.

Comment: yes after selecting that also it showing the same error message thank u so much for ur reply.